# WCF Restful post Services returns BAD REQUEST(400)

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest

I am trying from few days to consume wcf restful service but it is giving me bad reqeust. Please Help me out.

Here is my configuration file

```
<system.serviceModel>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="state" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="None"></security>

    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="RESTFUL_DEMO.Web.services.Calc">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="state" binding="webHttpBinding" name="Http" contract="RESTFUL_DEMO.Web.services.ICalc"/>
    <endpoint address="abcd" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsHttp" contract="RESTFUL_DEMO.Web.services.ICalc"/>

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MEX" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

  </service>
</services>
```

my interface for service contract and datacontract is as follows.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface ICalc
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "dowork", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    int DoWork(Enroll a);
}


[DataContract]
public class Enroll
{
    public Enroll()
    {

    }
    public Enroll(string Avalue)
    {
        this.Avalue = Avalue;
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Avalue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}
```

my code to consume the service is as follows

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/RESTFUL_DEMO.Web/services/Calc.svc/dowork") as HttpWebRequest;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"d:\test.xml");
        string sXML = doc.InnerXml;
        request.ContentLength = sXML.Length;
        request.ContentType = "test/xml; charset=utf-8";
        var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sw.Write(sXML);
        sw.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String result = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: `request.ContentType = "test/xml; charset=utf-8";` should be `request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";`

Comment: `sXML.Length` maybe different than the length of bytes written to stream if it contains non-ascii chars..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a small mistake while consuming Rest service. You have specified ContentType of request to **test**/xml; charset=utf-8 but it should be text/xml or application/xml.

```
request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
```

or it should be

```
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my method in service interface IBookService.cs is like below

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/Book", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
IList<Book> UpdateBook(Book book);
```

and in my client I was giving

```
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
```

instead of

```
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/json";
```

That fixed my problem. Please see below for my complete solution

```
 private void btnUpdateBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/json";                   
                Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://localhost:8085/BookService/Book");

                Book updateBook = new Book() { Id = 3, Name = "UpdateBook Name 3", Price = 77.77f };

                MemoryStream requestStream = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer requestSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Book));
                requestSerializer.WriteObject(requestStream, updateBook);

                client.UploadDataCompleted += OnUpdateBookCompleted;
                client.UploadDataAsync(uri, "PUT",requestStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    void OnUpdateBookCompleted(object sender, UploadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] result = e.Result as byte[];
        MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream(result);
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IList<Book>));
        IList<Book> books = (IList<Book>)serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);

        bindingSource1.DataSource = books;
        dvBooks.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Get the service up and running in an instance of Visual Studio, then use the [Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to make sure the service is running OK.

Open a new instance of VS and add a service reference which will build the client code for you, then use this client to call the service.

Comment: The WCF Test Client does not work for WCF Restful endpoints. It would be consuming the endpoint with WSHttpBinding, which won't help to solve the original question. See more info at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx.